# determine whether the characters of the string are in their correct sequence using regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I got some challenge I would call simple but yet turned to be tricky!
I want to use regex to determine whether characters of a string are in their correct sequence.
for example

```
"123" or "abc" #---> this should return true
"wxe" or "232" #---> this should return false
```

Is there a regular expression I can use to get a solution?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It is not entirely clear from your question what you mean by 'correct sequence'.

From your examples, it seems to mean lexicographic order but what about gaps (`'abd'` or '`169`') or repeats (`'112255'`)?

You can import strings in lexicographic order from the `string` module and then construct a pattern from them. The match will then only be if the target is itself in the same order as the characters in the strings.

If you want single characters, gaps ok, no repeats, use the `?` meta character meaning '0 or 1' of the proceeding character.

```
from string import digits, ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase
import re

meta='?'

pat=meta.join(digits+ascii_uppercase+ascii_lowercase)+meta
#pat='0?1?2?...x?y?z?'

for e in ["123", "abc", "abd", "wxe", "232", "11225"]:
    print(e, re.fullmatch(pat, e))
```

Prints:

```
123 <re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='123'>
abc <re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='abc'>
abd <re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='abd'>
wxe None
232 None
11225 None
```

If you want to match something like `'11225'` as being 'in order' change `?` to `*` to allow repeats of the same character.

---

If you mean that `'abc'` should match but `'abd'` should not since there is a gap, you can also use the same method but reverse the pattern and target:

```
from string import digits, ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase
import re

st=digits+ascii_uppercase+ascii_lowercase

for e in ["123", "abc", "abd", "wxe", "232", "11225"]:
    print(e, re.search(e, st))
```

Prints:

```
123 <re.Match object; span=(1, 4), match='123'>
abc <re.Match object; span=(36, 39), match='abc'>
abd None
wxe None
232 None
11225 None
```

So it depends what you mean by 'correct sequence'.

---

Note: You can also do this in languages (Ruby, Perl, Python) that allow code to be run on the replacement value of a regex.

Here is an example in Python:

```
for e in ["123", "abc", "abd", "wxe", "232", "11225"]:
    print(e, e==re.sub(r'(.)(?=(.))', 
            lambda m: "" if m.group(1)>m.group(2) else m.group(1), e))
```

Prints:

```
123 True
abc True
abd True
wxe False
232 False
11225 True
```

Same in Perl:

```
echo '1223' | perl -nE '$s=$_; s/(.)(?=(.))/($1 gt $2) ? "" : $1/ge; say $s eq $_ ?  "True" : "False";'
```